# Assigning an integer to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, variable-assignment

I am trying to ask a user:
If they draw an ace, ask if they want it to be 1 or 11.
They answer an integer and it is MEANT to set it to either 1 or 11. Unfortunately when I run this stays as the ace.

```
import time
import random
from random import *

suits = ["Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"]
cards = ["Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"]

def drawcard():
    global newcardtype
    global newcardsuit
    global newcard
    newcardtype = cards[randint(0,11)] ##User interface & Console
    newcardsuit = suits[randint(0,3)] ##User interface & Console
    newcard = newcardtype, newcardsuit ##Console to read and understand
    print("You picked up: " + str(newcardtype) + " of " + str(newcardsuit) + ".")

suits[0] = "♡"
suits[1] = "♢"
suits[2] = "♧"
suits[3] = "♤"    

cards[10] = 10
cards[11] = 10
cards[12] = 10

while(True):
    test = input("New card? ")
    if test == "y":
        drawcard()
        if newcardtype == cards[0]:
            acequestion = int(input("You picked up an Ace. Would you like your Ace to be 1 or 11?: "))
            if acequestion == 1:
                cards[0] = int(1)
            if acequestion == 11:
                cards[0] = int(11)
        print(newcardtype)
```

It's in working order, but I want `cards[0]` which is "ace" to be equal to either 1 or 11 based on the answer to the "acequestion" question.

Comment: `int(1)` ?? overkill.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre probably, but I wanted to be safe than sorry. I'm new to python, and I wanted to make sure it works so I didn't get confused with errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the number 1 or 11 to `cards[0]`, but that doesn't change the object or value to which `newcardtype` refers, so it still has the value `'ace'`. If you want to change the value of `newcardtype` you have to assign 1 or 11 to it as well.

Comment: Take a look at Ned Batchelder's talk [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html).